# Login to Active Directory via google

Tags: active-directory, google-apps, saml, adfs

I am trying to figure-out an option for authenticating a user, via ADFS, in AD using a google account. Essentially, what I would like to do is to allow a user to sign into my service using their google apps or gmail account and get access to some resources which currently require AD user accounts. Ultimately, I am trying to prevent having to create AD users for each and every client of my service.

I have seen lots of examples of how to authenticate the other direction. Allowing an AD authenticated user to login to google apps. But, I am coming-up short trying to find an example that goes the other direction. I feel like I have seen this in the past. But, maybe I was confused. Is tis possible? If so, does anybody know of any good resources describing how to set-up google, adfs, ad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by providing another SAML2 IDP which, in turn, could make use of [Google OAuth2WebServer](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer).

[image]

This means that you can set up, e.g., [SimpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/) and adding an auth module which uses [the Google API Client Library por PHP](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started)